# Using settings fragment, the action bar covers up the top preference

Tags: android, settings, preferences

I have a simple app with a single page preferences implemented in fragment style. I am running on tablets with Android 4.x (several versions). When I open the preferences page, the action bar covers up the top preference item. My work-around is to have a dummy first item, but of course this is dumb. I just don't know how to keep the action bar and have the preferences start below the action bar. I'm not programming for the action bar, it just shows up.

[Screen shot of problem](http://millermicrosystems.com/PreferencesProblem.png)

Preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_AdaptToRoomXXX"
        android:title="This is the dummy item as a spacer" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key         ="@string/pref_TimeFormat"
        android:title       ="@string/action_setTimeFormat"
        android:summary     ="@string/action_setTimeFormat"
        />

    <ListPreference 
        android:key="@string/pref_DateFormat"
        android:title="@string/action_setDateFormat"
        android:summary="@string/action_setDateFormat"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/action_setDateFormat"
        android:entries="@array/action_setDateFormat_options"
        android:entryValues="@array/action_setDateFormat_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/action_setDateFormat_default" />

    <ListPreference 
        android:key="@string/pref_TextColor"
        android:title="@string/action_setTextColor"
        android:summary="@string/action_setTextColor"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/action_setTextColor"
        android:entries="@array/action_setTextColor_colors"
        android:entryValues="@array/action_setTextColor_values"
        android:defaultValue="@string/action_setTextColor_default" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_DimOnBattery"
        android:title="@string/action_setDimOnBattery"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Usually your `ActionBar` shouldn't overlay the content. Check if you have set `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` for your window, i.e. ...

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

... is called inside of your activity. If so - remove it.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add the `app:layout_behavior` attribute to the `<FrameLayout />` container of the `PreferenceFragment` in your layout file.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by adding these 2 attrs into styles.xml

```
<!-- Make setting content not covering by actionbar -->
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
<item name="android:clipToPadding">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across this issue: I had this occur on `4.4` and `5.0` phones with the design library app bar. Tried the above solutions to no avail. What did work was changing my fragment's hosting activity to `LinearLayout`, resolving the issue.